# How to know that an activity is reshown?

Tags: android

Inside an `activity` there is a button which when clicked shows an `AlertDialog`. After this dialog is dismissed I want to execute some tasks if the user clicked the `BUTTON_NEGATIVE` of the Dialog. So how to recognize that the activity is `reshown` ? I know activity `life-cycle` and I implemented the known life-cycle states but they don't start the task I want to execute !

I implement onDismissListener but it crash :

```
private OnDismissListener dismissListener = new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        if (dialog instanceof ConfirmChoixDownloadDialogView) {

            if (btnClicked == OUI) {

                ...

            }

            else if (btnClicked == NON) { // the BUTTON_NEGATIVE


                Intent i = new Intent(activity, SelectionQuartierActivity.class); // activity is the activity containing the button which shows the Dialog
                activity.startActivity(i);

            }

        }

    }

};
```

Comment: Why don't you consider using shared preferences to flag that the activity was shown ?

Comment: Save some flag into SharedPreferences (look up in docs), for example: 'isFirstLaunch' (false by default). And onResume in your activity check this flag from SharedPreferences. Something like this. Hope you got the idea

Comment: Where does your application crash? Is there an error message or a call stack?

Comment: it crash at the code `activity.startActivity(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I found a tip to start the `activity` from the `activity` which opened the `Dialog` by implementing the `onWindowFocusChanged` method of the `activity` and setting a `public static` variable of the `activity` inside the `OnDismissListener` of the `Dialog` !

Answer (score 0):

Add on OnDismissListener to the Dialog:

```
AlertDialog a = new AlertDialog();
a.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: I already implemented this , and I want to start the task here but app crash !

Comment: If your app is crashing, that's a different issue! Make a SO post for your app crashing and I'll take a look!

Comment: I edited my post to include the code of the listener.